# Get the name of class & function sent to another class

Tags: ios, swift, logging

I've created a small class which acts as a logger inside the app.

I am calling to from all over the app as followed:

```
Logger.log(.debug, "The message")
```

And it prints the log.

There is a way for the Logger class to know which class is the sender and from which method the .log func was called without sending the data by myself and without them inherit from the same class? I want it to print:

```
"[CLASS/#function]: The message"
```

This is the method:

```
static func log(_ logType: LogType, _ message: String) {
    switch logType {
        case .error:
            print("Error: \(message)"
        case .blabla:
            print("Blabla: \(message)"
    }
}
```

***Example:***

In class MainVC inside viewDidLoad:

```
Logger.log(.debug, "View loaded!")
```

Logger class prints:

```
[MainVC/#viewDidLoad]: View loaded!
```

Comment: You can use #function, #file, #line, #column in this place

Comment: But this will give me the name of the current #function, #file, #line & #column. I want the sender's info.

Comment: @YossiTsafar You have to use them as default parameter values. Default parameter values are evaluated in the caller's context. Look at `fatalError`, `print` and similar functions, they do the same.